How to provide default props for React component in TypeScript?
Note: before marking as duplicate, make sure that linked solution (if any, I failed to find one) has the same prop notion as in code below.
I have done some research about setting default prop values for React components, but it seems like I'm defining them in a slightly different way than most of examples and I'm struggling to use the Javascript-default-object-property-value notion.
My current component looks like this:
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

function DialogOk(props: { 
    children: ReactNode, 
    show: boolean, 
    setShow: (newShow: boolean) => void, 
    header: string, 
    onOk: (() => void) | undefined }) {

    const [t] = useTranslation();

    function onHide() {

        props.setShow(false);
    }

    function onOk() {

        props.setShow(false);
        if (props.onOk !== undefined)
            props.onOk();
    }

    return (
        <Modal show={props.show} onHide={onHide} centered>
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>{props.header}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>{props.children}</Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={onOk}>{t("common:ok")}</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
}

DialogOk.defaultProps = {

    onOk: undefined
};

export { DialogOk }

When I try to modify the line with prop definitions (added line breaks for clarity):
function DialogOk(props: { 
    children: ReactNode, 
    show: boolean, 
    setShow: (newShow: boolean) => void, 
    header: string, 
    onOk: (() => void) | undefined = undefined }) {

I'm receiving the following error: A type literal property cannot have an initializer.
How should I set default value of props in this specific case?

...this has nothing to do with React or props, you are trying to assign a value to a variable in a type declaration. That won't work: types aren't values and values aren't types.

You need to put the default value in the javascript code, not in the typescript types. For example (stripping it down to just one prop for brevity):
function DialogOk({ onOk = undefined }: { onOk: (() => void) | undefined }) {

The code { onOk = undefined } is destructuring the props object into an onOk variable. And if that value happens to be undefined, it will default to... undefined. That particular default value isn't very useful, but as an example, if you wanted the default to be an empty function that would look like:
function DialogOk({ onOk = () => {} }: { onOk: (() => void) | undefined }) {
  // All subsequent code can assume that onOk is a function; undefined is impossible.

Or to make it more readable, i would usually do it like this:
interface DialogOkProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  show: boolean;
  setShow: (newShow: boolean) => void;
  header: string;
  onOk: (() => void) | undefined;
}

function DialogOk({
  children,
  show,
  setShow,
  header,
  onOk = () => {},
}: DialogOkProps) {
 // ...
}



Is it possible to achieve the same while still keeping props in a single parameter? (as in function DialogOk(props: { })) ?

Well, you could write code like const onOk = props.okOk === undefined ? () => {} : props.onOk. That's basically a longhand equivalent of the destructuring. Does that work for you?
